# Streaming mp3 files with django, read from a page with <audio>

Tags: python, django, audio-streaming

I'm trying to make a small app to stream my mp3 files with a web interface, and I thought about playing with  and do the server side in python with django.

I want to have urls like /stream/ID to stream the mp3 corresponding to that ID.
I made a view in django to serve these files using different methods, the last one I tried being the one described [here](http://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/django-file-and-stream-serving-performance-gotcha/)

If I access /stream/ID from firefox, it plays the mp3 directly with firefox-totem or some plugin like that. If I use the page with my audio player with the same url as the source it doesn't work at all (works with a link to an mp3 file served by apache).

here is the code of my view (only send one test file)

```
def stream(request):  
    resp =  HttpResponse(FileIterWrapper(open('/.../test.mp3',"rb")),mimetype='audio/mpeg')  
    resp['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize("/.../test.mp3")  
    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=test.mp3'  
    return resp
```

I cut the full path, it is not the problem.

When looking at the django runserver output, I noticed that each time the audio player tries, I get these 2 errors,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 281, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 321, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 417, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 318, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 42891)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 309, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 562, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 618, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 661, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

no problem/error when I acces the stream URL directly.

I tried the same in chromium (latest version, with ffmpeg-extra installed), it works fine with the mp3 from apache, but timeouts when using the stream url.

I tried setting different headers in the response, but with no success.
I'm currently setting the content-length, content-type and content-disposition

I'm looking for new ideas to try.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to observe your browser/media player/apache while it works correctly.

Comment: thanks for the answer. for some reason the streaming works now, probably some caching issue. I still get the errors in python, so I guess it's coming from request the browser makes to get the header of the file and tries to resume. I will look with wireshark if I see something that can explain it. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem