# Broken pipe during stream

Tags: python, django, stream

I have a project with Django I am working on where I want to stream some mp3 files.

I have this same issue:
[Streaming mp3 files with django, read from a page with <audio>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414394/streaming-mp3-files-with-django-read-from-a-page-with-audio)

Let me explain: I want **stream an ogg** with Django, and with an `<audio>` tag in my html page

I have a url like `domain.tld/song/show/X/`, where `X` is the id of my song.
I can stream with VLC (directly with the file path), I can stream during test, (I write what I receive and read it with VLC).

But when I open my browser and load my home page `domain.tld` where I have and `<\audio\>` balise with url `domain.tld/song/show/1/`, I get a big broken pipe, as if my client closed the connection.

I read on others post that some problems was resolved when they put server in production. So I push my app on server, use apache, with the `django.wgsi` like on djangoproject.com.

I am running python 2.7.3 on Debian 7 with Django version 1.5.
there my code:

Song/views.py

```
def playAudioFile(request, pk):
    f = get_stream_song(pk)# return a pipe from pipes.Template
    l = f.read() # the file is an ogg get by pydub.com
    f.close()
    size_read = 550000
    sr = size_read
    while sr == size_read:
        print "rep"
        r = l[:size_read]
        l=l[size_read:]
        sr = len(r)
        yield r
    time.sleep(0.1) 

#url : ~/song/show/X/
#@login_required
def show_song(request, pk):
        return StreamingHttpResponse(playAudioFile(request, pk), mimetype='audio/ogg',)
```

In my HTML, I just have that:

```
 <audio controls height="100" width="100" preload="auto">
    <source src="/.../song/show/1/" type="audio/ogg">
    <embed height="50" width="100" src="/.../song/show/1/">
  </audio>
```

The error looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 215, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 46392)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/lumy/SPhoque/SonoPhoque/SoPhoque/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 150, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 704, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I got this twice each time I try to stream.

---

Edit 15h 29/05:

I did what rahan suggested:
Looking at Firebug and Firefox debugger:

The client does:

```
GET 1   200 OK localhost:8000 537.1KB 4.71s

Headers
Response Headersview source
Date    Wed, 29 May 2013 13:08:54 GMT
Server  WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
Content-Type    audio/ogg
Request Headersview source
Host    localhost:8000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.12) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.12 Iceweasel/10.0.12
Accept  audio/webm,audio/ogg,audio/wav,audio/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,video/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Range   bytes=0-
Referer http://localhost:8000/
```

and details say that the total size for all documents is 1 MB (526 KB from cache)

Comment: Your client/browser is terminating the connection. You need to check that.

Comment: @Rohan with wireshark ? on the firefox debugger a get response 200 for the url /.../song/show/1/

Comment: Can use wireshark or also check in FF debugger if there is something.

Answer (score 1):

May be I am crossing your existing solution, i have a suggestion, for mp3 streaming use `nginx`/`apache` server, these days there is solution known as `sendfile`, for example in your case on django view

```
def send_file_header(server_type):
    header = "X-Sendfile" if server_type == "apache" else "X-Accel-Redirect"
    return header

@login_required
def show_song(request, pk):
    res =  HttpResponse()
    path = "/path/to/secret/x.mp3"
    response[send_file_header('nginx')] = path
    response['Content-Type']= "application/octet-stream"
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"x.mp3\""
    return response
```